# Finding total of prime numbers between two x1,x2, cant find mistake?

Tags: c++, function, loops

I need to find the sum of prime numbers between two numbers, say x1 and x2 inclusively, however i cant detect whats wrong?
for example if i entered 3 and 9 i would get 15 but i am getting 133!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int prime(int n1, int n2)
{
    int  count =0;
    bool prime = true;

    for (n1; n1 < n2; n1++)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < n1; i++)
        {
            if (n1 % i == 0) {
                prime = false;
                continue;
            }
            else
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;

}
int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    cout << " Enter values for n1 and n2 (n1 must be smaller than n2):   ";
    cin >> n1>>n2;


    cout << " Sum of prime numbers from " << n1 << " and till " << n2 << " inclusively : " << prime(n1, n2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: step thr' a debugger...the inner for loop seems problematic,

Comment: "*if i entered 3 and 9 i would get 15 but i am getting 133!*" When I try that, I get `16`

Comment: The code in the inner loop is wrong in several ways. You probably want to make an isPrime(int num) function and separate the prime checking out of the inner loop.

Comment: As an aside - Don't trust input from the user.  Assume that they're going to do bad things, and fail when they do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your prime function is not appropriate. This should be like.

```
int prime(int n1, int n2) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (n1; n1 < n2; n1++) {       
        bool prime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < n1; i++) {
            if (n1 % i == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( prime ) { // current n1 is prime 
            sum = sum + n1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You are not adding anything if your n1 is prime.

Comment: You can speed up it a little bit with `i < sqrt(n1)` instead of `i < n1`

Comment: I am slightly confused my mistake was only because i had the "bool prime = true;" outside the loop?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `i <= sqrt(n1)`

Answer (score 3):

I am a big believer in the one loop per function. This is a very good example for this. Your inner loop checks if a number is prime so really it should be a function on its own:

```
bool is_prime(int n);

int sum_primes_between(int n1, int n2)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (; n1 <= n2; n1++)
    {
        if (is_prime(n1))
            sum += n1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now not only it's easier to read, but you can better test individual parts of code. You can test that `is_prime` is correct and after that you can test `num_primes_between` is correct. If you had gone this route from the start you wouldn't even have had the bug you currently have with detecting if a number is prime.

---

And here is an even neater solution with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
using namespace ranges;

bool is_prime(int n);

int sum_primes_between(int n1, int n2)
{
    return accumulate(view::ints(n1, n2 + 1) | view::filter(is_prime), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers provided so far respect the requirement of being inclusive.
Here's a corrected version including an optimized algorithm to check for primality:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool is_prime(int n) {
    // handle special cases
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n <= 3) {
        return true;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    /* because we covered multiples of 2 and 3 we can reduce the number of checks
    drastically */
    for(int i = 5, r = sqrt(n); i =< r; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
int sum_of_primes(int n1, int n2) {
    int sum = 0;
    // loop from n1 up to n2
    for ( ;n1 <= n2; n1++) {
        if (is_prime(n1)) {
            sum += n1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    cout<<"The sum of primes between 2 and 15 is: "<<sum_of_primes(2,15)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your original code didn't calculate the sum of primes, you simply incremented your count variable on every iteration that didn't find a divisor of the current number you were checking.

Comment: I may miss something, but in is_prime(), if I understand well, the second test should be `n%(i+2)` and not `(n%i) + 2`. Moreover, it should be `ì <= r` and not `i < r`. (I made this mistake myself in a previous comment !)